# How do I post 3 values from a form into 1?

Tags: php, post, get

I have the following date picker with 3 different select ids

```
<form id="testform" method="get" action="../Untitled-1.html">
    <select id="date-sel-dd" name="date-sel-dd">
      <option value="-1">Day</option>

      <option value="1">1st</option>
      <option value="2">2nd</option>
      <option value="3">3rd</option>
      <option value="4">4th</option>
      <option value="5">5th</option>
      <option value="6">6th</option>

      <option value="7">7th</option>
      <option value="8">8th</option>
      <option value="9">9th</option>
      <option value="10">10th</option>
      <option value="11">11th</option>
      <option value="12">12th</option>

      <option value="13">13th</option>
      <option value="14">14th</option>
      <option value="15">15th</option>
      <option value="16">16th</option>
      <option value="17">17th</option>
      <option value="18">18th</option>

      <option value="19">19th</option>
      <option value="20">20th</option>
      <option value="21">21st</option>
      <option value="22">22nd</option>
      <option value="23">23rd</option>
      <option value="24">24th</option>

      <option value="25">25th</option>
      <option value="26">26th</option>
      <option value="27">27th</option>
      <option value="28">28th</option>
      <option value="29">29th</option>
      <option value="30">30th</option>

      <option value="31">31st</option>
    </select>
    <select id="date-sel-mm" name="date-sel-mm">
      <option value="-1">Month</option>
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>

      <option value="4">April</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
      <option value="6">June</option>
      <option value="7">July</option>
      <option value="8">August</option>
      <option value="9">September</option>

      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select id="date-sel" name="date-sel">
      <option value="-1">Year</option>
      <option value="2012">2012</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I need to get the values from these 3 differnt select fields and post it with the form to a new named: 'arrival'.
When I submit to the page I want my url to look like:

mydomain.php?arrival=date-sel-dd/date-sel-mm/date-sel

Comment: What is the point of doing this? It seems like it would make your code unnecessarily more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array.

Rename all `select` with `arrival[]`.

In your php page you can get that value as an array. Try:

```
print_r($_POST['arrival']);
```

If you want to join the date use:

```
$date = implode('/', $_POST['arrival']);

header('Location: mydomain.php?arrival=' . $date);
```